# Formalize in propositional logic:

Tags: logic

Formalize in propositional logic:

A) It rained heavily.

B) Susanna is blonde and Agnès is brunette.

C) Enter or exit.

D) He arrives but looks sad.

E) It is not true that it rains and does not shine.

F) If you do not shut up, I will be angry and punish you.

G) Frogs are not enchanted princes.

H) It is not true that the book is red and expensive.

I) Do your homework now or, if you do not do it, you'll have to do it tomorrow.

Comment: That's a command and not a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

[image]

Here is the answer.!!!!!!!!!!!!!!